# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 “No such file or directory”) when configuring cluster

Tags: mysql, mariadb, clustering, galera, mariadb-10.1

I have 3 MariaDB nodes. 
Want to configure cluster.
Specified in *gcomm://* in *my.cnf* ips of all members in cluster according to [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/galera-cluster-address/).

And added `?pc.wait_prim=no` at then of *gcomm://ip1,ip2,ip3*

Then *mysqld* process starts on each VM, but when i try to it connect with *mysql -uroot -ppass* in order to run

```
SET GLOBAL wsrep_provider_options="pc.bootstrap=1";
```

error pops:

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

error.log of each process shows:

```
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529975699392 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connecting to group 'my_wsrep_cluster', peer '10.0.0.42:,10.0.0.44:,10.0.0.43:'
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529975699392 [Note] WSREP: (71d7b5ed, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection established to 71d7b5ed tcp://10.0.0.44:45
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529975699392 [Warning] WSREP: (71d7b5ed, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') address 'tcp://10.0.0.44:4567' points to own listeddress, blacklisting
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529975699392 [Note] WSREP: (71d7b5ed, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection established to 6ac0d002 tcp://10.0.0.42:45
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529975699392 [Note] WSREP: (71d7b5ed, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting on, nonlive peers:
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529975699392 [Note] WSREP: (71d7b5ed, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection established to 6bd1b1f9 tcp://10.0.0.43:45
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529975699392 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connected
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529975699392 [Note] WSREP: Changing maximum packet size to 64500, resulting msg size: 32636
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529975699392 [Note] WSREP: Shifting CLOSED -> OPEN (TO: 0)
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529975699392 [Note] WSREP: Opened channel 'my_wsrep_cluster'
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529975699392 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete.
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529635424000 [Note] WSREP: declaring 6ac0d002 at tcp://10.0.0.42:4567 stable
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529635424000 [Note] WSREP: declaring 6bd1b1f9 at tcp://10.0.0.43:4567 stable
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529635424000 [Warning] WSREP: no nodes coming from prim view, prim not possible
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529635424000 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(NON_PRIM,6ac0d002,2) memb {
        6ac0d002,0
        6bd1b1f9,0
        71d7b5ed,0
} joined {
} left {
} partitioned {
})
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529627031296 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = no, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 2, memb_num = 3
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529627031296 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [28, 28]
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529627031296 [Note] WSREP: Trying to continue unpaused monitor
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529627031296 [Note] WSREP: Received NON-PRIMARY.
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529975253760 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: :-1, view# -1: non-Primary, number of nodes: 3, my ind protocol version -1
2018-02-01 15:13:23 140529975253760 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
2018-02-01 15:13:26 140529635424000 [Note] WSREP: (71d7b5ed, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 71d7b5ed with addr tcp://10.0.0.44timed out, no messages seen in PT3S
2018-02-01 15:13:26 140529635424000 [Note] WSREP: (71d7b5ed, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off
```

Why does it happen and what's wrong?

Comment: Not related to the socket issue, but for bootstrapping you can use `sudo service mysql bootstrap` or `sudo service mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster` or with systemd: `galera_new_cluster`. (Though, not sure if perhaps it expects the mysqld process not to be running when issuing these commands.)

Answer (score 2):

Check your config files `/etc/my.cnf` and `/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf` and look for the socket parameter. Make sure it's the same for client and server. A good place for the socket parameter is in the [client-server] section in `/etc/my.cnf`. The socket file is created by the MariaDB server when it starts up.

Note that there are other places where MariaDB config files could reside, and these could potentially override your settings in the two files mentioned above. For more details, see [this page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-with-mycnf/) in the MariaDB KB.

Also note that you may be able to connect to MariaDB through TCP rather than through the socket. You can specify that you want to use TCP rather than the socket with `mysql ... --protocol=TCP`. If this is successful, you can then do `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'socket';` to find out where the socket file really is (or should be). You can then connect with `mysql ... --socket=/path/to/file.sock` or edit the config files so that the client reads it correctly from there.

In some cases you may also be able to figure out what socket file location is used by listing the processes: `ps -ef | grep mysql` which could output something like

```
root     23900     1  0 13:27 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/vserv-03.pid
mysql    24402 23900  0 13:27 ?        00:00:50 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --wsrep_on=ON --wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/vserv-03.err --open-files-limit=65535 --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/vserv-03.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --wsrep_start_position=98b22222-aa16-1114-ba1a-886633c6b8eb:55133333
```

As you can see here (scroll right), it's using a socket at `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`.

**EDIT:** 
A really good way of finding the location of the socket file is:

```
netstat -ln | grep mysql
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     22418    /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock is the same for client and server

Comment: @user1264304 Are you able to log in over TCP instead of the socket? `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -ppass` Then you can do `show variables like 'socket';` It might be interesting to see if that agrees with your config files.

Comment: @user1264304 I've updated my answer with several more ideas. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me after a reboot...
The socket file couldn't be found anywhere. In my case it should have been in:
`/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

In my case, I fixed it by doing:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

After these steps, the socket appeared in mysqld directory and I could start mysql (mariaDB).

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem and this fixed it.

Comment: It doesn't work that way.

Comment: @metabuddy could you explain what you mean?

Comment: I mean, I have the same situation where the socket file is missing. I ran the two update commands and rebooted but the file wasn't created.

Comment: @metabuddy make sure you also run apt-get upgrade, hopefully that will fix it. If not google update/upgrade not working as there could be issues with it not fully upgrading.