# Can't use ODBC to connect to MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, linux, odbc, unixodbc, handler-socket

Linux Mint 20 (Ubuntu 20).

MariaDB version:
"mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.7.3-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2"

LibreOffice 6.4.7.2.

I want to run LibreOffice Base as the front end, using ODBC. I previously had MySQL installed in this OS and managed to get ODBC working for LibreOffice Base. Now I have removed MySQL and installed MariaDB.

**Incidentally, I am now beginning to wonder whether this a LibreOffice glitch. Wouldn't be the first. Any successful experience of getting ODBC to work with MariaDB (specifically) in Linux could be helpful. Though in fact I seem possibly to have got it working in fact (see below: isql with my configured DSN works!).**

I have tried to follow the MariaDB instructions [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/creating-a-data-source-with-mariadb-connectorodbc/).

I have put the file libmaodbc.so in /usr/lib64/. I believe this is the main connector file.

I have made a file /etc/odbcinst.ini as follows:

```
[MariaDB]
Description=MariaDB Connector/ODBC v.3.0
Driver=/usr/lib/libmaodbc.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/libmaodbc.so
UsageCount=1
```

and a file /etc/odbc.ini as follows:

```
[localdb]
Description           = MariaDB connection to  database
Driver                = MariaDB
Database              = localdb
Server                = localhost
User                  = user_mike
Password              = user_mike
Port                  = 3306
Socket                = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

When I try to connect using LO Base, this ODBC entry "localdb" is seen. But then when I test out the connection I get:

> [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

"Data source name"? But I *chose* the DSN. "default driver"? How might I specify that, I wonder!

Anyone know what I should do? My theory is that the odbc.ini file references the odbcinst.ini file, which in turn drives the libmaodbc.so file.

NB if I go as far as trying to actually make the connection, i.e. to get a list of tables in the database in LO Base, I get

> The connection to the data source "xxx"* could not be established
>
> [ma-3.1.15]Can't connect to local server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)

* i.e. the LO Base filename minus the ".odb" extension.

I found [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/196837/102949). This led me to check my .cnf file(s), NB under /etc/mysql...

And also to check my socket (with the MariaDB service running):

```
mike@M17A:~/MariaDB_files$ netstat -ln | grep mysql
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     263752   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

... interesting: seems to suggest that the socket is alive and well.

Also I **can** connect using `isql localdb` from the CLI: doesn't this suggest things are set up OK?

So what might be the issue?

Comment: Would it help if you replaced "Server                = localhost" by "SERVER=localhost" and so for the other parameters too, as specified by https://mariadb.com/kb/en/creating-a-data-source-with-mariadb-connectorodbc/ ?

Comment: FYI: my location for the library is /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmaodbc.so.

Comment: Thanks... tried both of those: no joy. Interestingly, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc did already exist, with various files in it. I copied the (hopefully) 64-bit version of libmaodbc.so there, adjusted odbcinst.ini accordingly... still no change.

Comment: The 13 in `Can't connect to local server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)` by running `perror 13` indicates a permission denied

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to know. I'll do some research into how I might try to do something about that.

Comment: srwxrwxrwx  1 mysql mysql    0 Apr  5 11:13 mysqld.sock

Comment: Strange: when I put invalid information in /etc/odbc.ini, libreoffice base is still able to connect.

Comment: Yes, I have those permissions and ownership for mysqld.sock. Also directory /var/run/mysqld is `drwxr-xr-x mysql:root` and directory /var/run/mysql (which I had to create) is `drwxr-xr-x mysql:mysql`. Yes, that is strange that LO Base can still connect: are you definitely using ODBC (rather than JDBC?).

Comment: One is never too old to learn: when the server is localhost, MariaDB always tries (and listens on)  the default socket location.  Can't be disabled,  If you had to create /var/run/mysql, are you sure MariaDB is using it?   I suppose your netstat proves it is.  "lsof" shows the same?

Comment: I'm not a Linux expert: I've never heard of `netstat` or `lsof` (though just googled them and they seem useful/powerful). I created the mysql directory as a result of much trawling around SO and AskUbuntu etc. At this point I'm kind of out of ideas! By the way, I *can* use the JDBC connection to use Base forms... but when I had MySQL it was MUCH slower. NB I need to use MariaDB to "harmonise" with MariaDB on my W10 boot on this machine (also because I always go for FOSS if possible).

Comment: OK.  So, how did you install MariaDB?  I don't know Mint or Ubuntu, but I used to work with Debian.  The installation and startup of MariaDB should have taken care of /var/run/mysql, unless systemd has thrown a spanner in the works.

Comment: "I have put the file libmaodbc.so in /usr/lib64/."  Where did you get this and the "Driver64" idea?

Comment: FYI: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/ODBC-278